Autoshut down vm using Azure SDK fluent C#
This is my code to create vm in Azure using the Azure SDK fluent. My question is: I need to set auto shutdown option while creating VM, I need to set the time while creating the VM so in that case the VM will get poweroff when the time arrives. Is that possible? Please let me know.
public async Task<VmResponse> DoCreateVm(VMConfigurationParameter objvm)
{
        VmResponse response = new VmResponse();
        LogDAL objlog = new LogDAL();
        var usernameWithoutSpaces = objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "");
        var vNetName = $"{char.ToUpper(usernameWithoutSpaces.Replace(".", "")[0])}{usernameWithoutSpaces.Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, usernameWithoutSpaces.Replace(".", "").Length - 1))}{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}-vnet";
        var vNetAddress = "172.16.0.0/16";
        var subnetName = "default";
        var subnetAddress = "172.16.0.0/24";
        var nicName = $"{char.ToUpper(objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "")[0])}{objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Length - 1))}{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}";
        var publicIPName = $"{char.ToUpper(objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "")[0])}{objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Length - 1))}{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}";
        var nsgName = $"{char.ToUpper(objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "")[0])}{objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Length - 1))}{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}";
        var username = $"{char.ToUpper(objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "")[0])}{objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Length - 1))}{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}";
        var userpassword = $"{char.ToUpper(objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "")[0])}{objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Length - 1))}@{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}";
        var vmname = $"{char.ToUpper(objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "")[0])}{objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Substring(1, Math.Min(5, objvm.UserName.Replace(" ", "").Replace(".", "").Length - 1))}{objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Substring(Math.Max(0, objvm.UserNumber.ToString().Length - 6))}-VM";

        try
        {
                string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Credentials"];
                var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(filePath);
                filePath = string.Empty;
                var azure = Azure.Authenticate(credentials).WithDefaultSubscription();
                string vm_ResGroup = "SSIS_Student"; 
                var resourceGroupName = await DoGetResourceGroupName(azure, vm_ResGroup);
                var details_resgrp = await DoGetResourceGroupName(azure, objvm.ExamName); //getting main details from the main resource group
                var (galleryname, imagename) = await DoGetGalleryImageDetails(azure, objvm.ExamName);
                if (resourceGroupName != "" && galleryname != "" && imagename != "" && details_resgrp!="")
                {
                    var captureImage = azure.GalleryImages.GetByGallery(details_resgrp, galleryname, imagename);
                if (captureImage != null)
                {
                    //var security = captureImage.RecommendedVirtualMachineConfiguration;

                    //var regionName = await getRegion();
                    var network = azure.Networks.Define(vNetName)
                            .WithRegion(captureImage.Location)
                            .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                            .WithAddressSpace(vNetAddress)
                            .WithSubnet(subnetName, subnetAddress)
                            .Create();
                    var nsg = azure.NetworkSecurityGroups.Define(nsgName)
                        .WithRegion(captureImage.Location)
                        .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                        .DefineRule("Allow-RDP")
                            .AllowInbound()
                            .FromAnyAddress()
                            .FromAnyPort()
                            .ToAnyAddress()
                            .ToPort(3389)
                            .WithProtocol(SecurityRuleProtocol.Tcp)
                            .WithPriority(100)
                            .Attach()
                        .Create();
                    var publicIP = azure.PublicIPAddresses.Define(publicIPName)
                            .WithRegion(captureImage.Location)
                            .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                            .WithStaticIP()
                            .Create();
                    //You need a network security group for controlling the access to the VM

                    var nic = azure.NetworkInterfaces.Define(nicName)
                             .WithRegion(captureImage.Location)
                             .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                             .WithExistingPrimaryNetwork(network)
                             .WithSubnet(subnetName)
                             .WithPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
                             .WithExistingPrimaryPublicIPAddress(publicIP)
                             .WithExistingNetworkSecurityGroup(nsg)
                             .Create();

                    //var security = security

                    var newVM = azure.VirtualMachines.Define(vmname)
                        
                                                     .WithRegion(captureImage.Location)
                                                     
                                                     .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
                                                     
                                                     .WithExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(nic)
                                                     
                                                     .WithWindowsCustomImage(captureImage.Id)
                                                     
                                                     .WithAdminUsername(username)
                                                     
                                                     .WithAdminPassword(userpassword)
                                                     
                                                     .WithComputerName(vmname)
                                                     
                                                     .WithSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.StandardD4sV3)
                                                     
                                                     .Create();
                    // newVM.Restart();

                    response.responseCode = "200";
                    response.responseMessage = "VM Created";
                    response.ipAddress = publicIP.Inner.IpAddress.ToString();
                    response.userName = username;
                    response.userPassword = userpassword;
                    response.vmname = vmname;
                    response.region = newVM.RegionName;
                    response.vmId = newVM.Id;

                    if (newVM != null)
                    {
                        DateTime shutdown = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4);
                        ScheduleShutdown(newVM.Id, shutdown, azure);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                        response.responseCode = "100";
                        response.responseMessage = "VM Not able to create";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                    response.responseCode = "400";
                    response.responseMessage = "Resource-Group , Image Not exist";
            }
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var message = ex.Message.ToString();
            //objlog.LogExceptionToFile(message);
            response.responseCode = "500";
            response.responseMessage = message;
        }

        return response;
    }

I need a solution to auto shutdown while creating VM using Azure SDK fluent and C#

Try adding these to azure.VirtualMachines.Define(vmname):
.withAutoShutdown()
.withShutdownMode(AutoShutdownSchedulePowerState.STOP_VM)
.withTimeZone("Eastern Standard Time")
// Change to your desired timezone
.withDailyUsageTime("2100")
// 24 hour format shutdown time (HHmm)

.
